# How to get XML attributes from XML with an unknown number of rows

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that allows me to get xml data from ONE row of xml from a specified column.

However, Product can have 1 UPC child, or a lot.

How can I alter my query to return all the existing children of Product?

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML =
    (SELECT ProductsXML
     FROM Products
     WHERE ProductId= 1)
SELECT 
    a.b.value('Product[1]/UPC[1]/@upccode','DATE') as UPC,
    a.b.value('Product[1]/UPC[1]/@dateadded','DATE') as DateAdded
    FROM @MyXML.nodes('xml')a(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML;
SET @MyXML =
    N'<xml>
        <Product>
            <UPC upccode="1237" dateadded="10/9/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="1236" dateadded="10/8/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="1235" dateadded="10/7/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="1234" dateadded="10/6/2012"/>
        </Product>
    </xml>';

SELECT 
    a.b.value('@upccode','int') as UPC,
    a.b.value('@dateadded','date') as DateAdded
FROM
    @MyXML.nodes('xml/Product/UPC')a(b);
```